# Encoding trouble with Facebook/Twitter API Emojis

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, twitter, emoji

I'm very new to PHP and I'm having some encoding issues with emojis in the Facebook/Twitter API

The data comes in and I see emojis represented like so: \u2026

after json_decode the emojis look like this: â€¦

and on my website they look like â€¦.

I'd like to handle them properly so they can be visible on the website or worst case just strip them out.  I found an js emoji library that can help if I can get the emojis in the right format. https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji

The twitter code looks like this:

```
            $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: $auth"),
                          //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                          CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

            $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $json = curl_exec($feed);
        curl_close($feed);
        $twitter_data = json_decode($json, true);
```

The facebook code looks like this:

```
        $requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
        $fb_response = json_decode($requests);
        $parseresponse = $fb_response->data;
        $fbpost = "";
        if (isset($parseresponse[0]->message))
        {
            $fbpost = $parseresponse[0]->message;
            $fbpost = str_replace("’", "'", $fbpost);
        }
```

After retrieving the API data, I'm saving the results to a mysql database and then displaying the posts from mysql to the website to avoid unnecessary API calls.

How can I get the FB/Twitter API emojis to work with https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji ?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely met an encoding issue. I would suggest you to try following:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
// content retrieval
$fb_response = json_decode($requests, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Also yo umight want to ensure you are running php version >= 5.2.0. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a emojis to php library called Emoji for PHP that will handle the conversion for you, It is very easy to use. You can download a copy here:

```
http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/
```

Comment: I tried using this.  I ran the emoji_google_to_unified method on the data but nothing changed.  I tried it before and then after the json_decode.  No luck.

Answer (score 0):

\u2026 is no emoji. It is a an ellipsis and looks like `…`: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm

However it is definitely a multibyte character. And when it looks like `â€¦`, something with the encoding is wrong somewhere.

Try to find the point where it breaks. Maybe on the way to the database (or on the way back?)? Take care that everything is in the same unicode encoding (I guess you use UTF8?), the connection to the database and the database table/field itself too.

If you print the strings directly (so before you save them to the DB), do they look fine? If not, check if viewing multibyte characters works at all in on your site (e.g. `echo "…";`)? If not maybe your page is not rendered as UTF8 at all? In that case, check your encoding settings in the HTML and in the HTTP headers.

You can check just the json_decode() by executing the following:

```
$json = json_decode('{"test":"\u2026"}');
var_dump($json->test === '…'); // should output boolean true
```

If I output the ellipsis `…` on a UTF8 page, like the following, it looks fine:

```
<html doctype>
<meta charset="utf-8">
…
</html>
```

However, if I change the encoding in the menu to Western ISO-8859-1, I get your `â€¦`. It shows at least that the unicode string is interpreted as ISO-8859-1. Have you played with this setting?

Comment: I've tried printing the strings all along the process.  They come in as \u2026 and then change to â€¦ when json.decode is executed.

Comment: @mga911 Strange. I added two test cases in my answer. How do you check your output? In the browser, I guess?